# use basic auth based on query_string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication

I'm trying to protect urls containing a specific string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} foo
RewriteRule - [E=NEED_AUTH:1]
Options -Indexes
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Order allow,deny
allow from all
satisfy any
deny from env=NEED_AUTH
Require valid-user
```

I suppose this should bring up the authentication dialog when loading

```
index.php?format=foo
```

but it doesn't work. I tried several other RewriteConds like for example

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} format=foo
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=foo$
```

with no luck. Using

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

doesn't log anything.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 2):

To add to Jon's answer, I had a similar issue as the OP.  But I found that `allow from env=!NEED_AUTH` was not working so I had to reverse it in the Rewrite Condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !format=foo`  and then reverse the allow `allow from env=NEED_AUTH`.  So, here is the snippet that works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !foo=bar
RewriteRule ^ - [E=NO_AUTH:1]

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType basic
AuthName "Auth Needed"
AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/conf.d/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
Allow from           env=NO_AUTH
Satisfy              Any
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've turned on the rewrite engine using `RewriteEngine On`. Also, there's an error in your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule - [E=NEED_AUTH:1]
```

Needs to have 2 parameters before the flags:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=NEED_AUTH:1]
```

Aside from that, it doesn't look like you've setup authentication correctly. You'll need a `AuthName` to define the realm, apache won't do authentication without it. And I don't think you can force authentication with a `allow from all`, you might need to do this the other way around, by denying all and `allow from env=!NEED_AUTH`

Answer (score 0):

As described here ([Apache permissions based on querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648078/apache-permissions-based-on-querystring)), I cannot get the combination of "RewriteRule" and "Allow from env" working in Apache 2.4.6.